# Баг при использовании CSS-свойства transform

Tags: css, transform

При использовании CSS-свойства `transfrom` наблюдается пробел между HTML-элементами.

Что это вообще за пробел и как его можно **красиво** убрать?

Фигура тут не имеет значение. Важно именно решение проблемы без JS Canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/g2w6y7fm/1

```css
.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 45px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 120px solid red;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 120px solid red;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-left">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: у .left и .right поставь 99% left и right соответственно, и линии пропадут

Comment: Да, но будет некрасивый выступ в 1px.

Comment: тогда попробуй поставь 99.5%)

Comment: Перенеси код в вопрос.

Comment: Пришла идея использовать [`box-shadow`](https://webref.ru/css/box-shadow),.. но при его применении к блокам `.left` и `.right` также вылетает побочный эффект: http://jsfiddle.net/v2soxs7y/; и при применении к `.top-left` вроде бы те же выступы, что и при установке `left` и `right` в 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/pyn34112/.

Answer (score 2):

К `.top-left` добавляем `backface-visibility: hidden`.

```css
.top-left {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 45px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 120px solid red;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
}
.left {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 120px solid red;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-left">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yw066stw/

Comment: В хроме всё хорошо, но в mozille по прежнему остались пробелы

Answer (score 1):

2 вариант - добавить `translate3d( 0, 0, 1px);`

```css
.top-left {  
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 45px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: top right;  
  transform: rotate(-30deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 1px);
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 120px solid red;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 120px solid red;
  border-left: 70px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-left">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```